# Android Button is clicked even after Timer hides it

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

#### Problem :

When I keep clicking **super fast** on a button it triggers it clickListener once even after the button was already **hidden** by a **Timer**

#### Description :

I have a visible clickable button that will be turned to invisible by the end of a timer running in a ViewModel.

Each time I click on the button it will log : `I/ALogs: Button Clicked`

When the timer is finished, `onFinish()` will be called and it will log `Time Finished` and turns the button's visibility to `invisible` (it will turn a LiveData to `false` and I have an observer on this LiveData that will turn a binded variable to false (see code below))

#### Scenario :

I run the app and I click **super fast** on the button until it becomes invisible after the times ends.

#### Expectation :

```
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Time Finished
```

#### Reality :

```
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
I/ALogs: Time Finished
I/ALogs: Button Clicked
```

I can't understand why there is a `I/ALogs: Button Clicked` after `I/ALogs: Time Finished`. The button is supposed to be hidden by `onFinish()` so it should not trigger any listener after that.

This does not happen everytime, which makes me suspect something related to Asyncronous click or observer calls, Rendering Thread, ...

Coming from the Javascript world, I feel that it's something related to the equivalent of the EventLoop in Android, but I don't know if it exists or how the rendering order happens in Android apps.

#### Code :

##### Fragment :

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]
    binding.viewModel = viewModel

    viewModel.buttonVisibility.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        binding.visibility = it
    }
    return binding.root
}
```

#### ViewModel :

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
companion object {
    private const val DONE = 0L
    private const val ONE_SECOND = 1000L
    private const val TIMER_SECOND = 1000L
}

private var timer: CountDownTimer = createTimer()

private val _buttonVisibility = MutableLiveData(true)
val buttonVisibility: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _buttonVisibility

init {
    timer.start()
}

fun buttonClickAction() {
    Log.i("ALogs", "Button Clicked")
}

private fun createTimer(): CountDownTimer {
    return object : CountDownTimer(TIMER_SECOND, ONE_SECOND) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            Log.i("ALogs", "Time Ticking")
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            Log.i("ALogs", "Time Finished")
            _buttonVisibility.value = false
        }
    }
}
```

#### XML :

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.wazawaza.testingtimerandclick.ui.main.MainViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="visibility"
        type="Boolean" />

    <import type="android.view.View" />

</data>
.
.
.
<Button
.
.
    android:visibility="@{visibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
    android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.buttonClickAction()}"
.
.
./>
```

Comment: Still trying to figure it out and I have some theories: 
1- the user touches the button but before the click listener is triggered the onFinish() triggers it hides the button and then when it finished the scheduled button event listener runs.

2- the onFinish triggers but before it hides the button, the user touches it, the system will schedule this click event to run after onFinish finishs

Comment: I don't think theory 2 is true because at the beggining of onFinish() I added "SystemClock.sleep(3000)" to block everything and give me the chance as the user to click on the button. But after onFinish was done, the button's clickListener didn't fire.

Comment: And I think theory 1 is correct but not very sure. I added my blocking code `SystemClock.sleep(5000)` inside `onTick()` and I made it to execute only on last `onTick()` before `onFinish()`. So when the last tick was fired, the app froze for 5s. Meanwhile I clicked on the button and no ClickListner was fired. When the blocking stopped, `onTick` finished. Right after that `onFinish()` fired and hid the button. And only after that the Button ClickListner fired and logged `I/ALogs: Button Clicked` as the issue I described in my question.

Comment: by overriding dispatchTouchEvent() in main activity I could detect that the screen was sometimes touched then onFinish() fires then ClickListener and in some cases onFinish() -> touch -> clicklistener. I think that onFinish() is prioritized by android so it can interubte the link touch -> ClickListener And second thought is that rendering is no sync so we can have click on a button if we are quick enough after the hiding code triggers. But still I don't have a perfect explanation about what is happening